# Math.random predict

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Скажите, как угадать следующие хотя-бы пару чисел с такого кода javascript:

```
var number = Math.floor(99.9 * Math.random());
```

Можно ли как-то угадать следующее число?

Comment: Зависит от деталей реализации, если там стоит линейный конгруэнтный генератор, от которого известны параметры (а они обычно известны) то вычислить зная последний результат можно вычислить следующий.

Comment: я знаю и последние 10 результатов, но вид у них такой:  
34,  
12,  
1,  
94,  
и так далее. Можно как-то вычислить следующее число?

Comment: А что у вас за javascript? V8?

Comment: Можно, скорее всего. Ищите детали реализации генератора в вашем JSе, тогда будет более предметный разговор.

Comment: Да и зачем угадывать результат вызова, если его можно заменить?

Comment: На сервере обычный javascript, в коде используется просто вот так: 99.9*Math.random()

Comment: На сервере? Rhino? NodeJS?

Comment: Есть NodeJS и Appserv

Comment: Об этом спрашивали на [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84906/predicting-math-random-numbers).

Comment: при 99.9 * Math.random() неизвестно значение после точки, только целое число

Comment: У меня есть маленькое подозрение что это не так-то просто. Всё-таки псевдогенераторы придумали как раз чтобы получить максимально случайное и **непредсказуемое** число. Исследуйте движок, а не JS.
Однако правильнее спросить так: не решаете ли Вы [проблему молотка](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709)? Зачем Вам это?

Answer (score 1):

Если кратко - следующий результат вы никак не можете угадать. Существуют теории описывающие вариации работы генераторов и плотности распределения их результатов, но это отдельная история требующая более конкретные входные данные о рабочем окружении и в любом случае не дающая 100% точность угадывания.